# Airflow task processes keep running on kubernetes task pods

Tags: python-3.x, kubernetes, airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver

I am running airflow(**2.3.2**) on kubernetes cluster. Executor is set to `KubernetesExecutor`. Triggering a DAG creates individual pods for every task. The tasks are successfully getting triggered and completed. The status is getting updated on Airflow UI as well as in `dag_run` table. Even the DAG is marked as Success/Failed but the task pods keep on running. When I exec within the pod, I can see the task process is still running. Because of this the pods are not getting terminated.
Config in `airflow.cfg`:

```
delete_worker_pods = True
delete_worker_pods_on_failure = False
```